# How to check user credentials before registering a user while also uploading an image to aws s3

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3

I am trying to implement a registration route in my application. The flow is pretty simple. While using the application, the user has the opportunity to select a profile image (but he doesn't have to). Later on, the user is asked to register and enters an email.

Now, I would like to check on my registration route IF the email already exists BEFORE uploading the image to my S3 bucket. If it does exist, I want to send back a proper error message. If it does NOT exist, I would like to check if the user has send along an image and proceed to upload the image to S3 so I can store the link in my db and proceed to register the user.

***The Problem***

Im appending both the file and the email to a formData object like so. At this point the `file` ***can*** be empty. That depends if the user has selected a profile image or not.

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('avatar', this.variables.avatar);
formData.append('email', JSON.stringify(this.email));
```

The problem is that when making the request, either `req.file` is undefined or `req.body.email` is undefined. The reason for this is simple, I cannot acces the `req.body.email` BEFORE the image is uploaded to my s3 bucket. This would mean that everytime a user registers with an already existing email, the image gets send to my s3 bucket nonetheless.

This is my function to upload to aws:

```
const avatarImgUpload = multer({
  storage: multerS3({
    s3: s3,
    bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET,
    acl: 'public-read',
    key: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, path.basename(file.originalname, path.extname(file.originalname)) + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname))
    }
  }),
}).single('avatar');
```

And this is my register route:

```
router.post('/register', (req, res) => {
  //let email = JSON.parse(req.body.email);
  //The email is undefined because I am not using middleware 
  //like multer to be able to 'read' or 'acces' this

  //Ideally I would like to FIRST check if a user exists like so:
  //User.findOne({email: req.body.email})

  //If it does not exists, great! Continue to the 'avatarImgUpload' function that uploads to S3'
  //If not, send back an error message and end the request there.

  avatarImgUpload(req, res, (error) => {
    //Within this function I do have access to req.body.email because it uses multer.
    //However, like I said before this means that the check IF the user already exists
    //has to take place AFTER the image is uploaded to my S3 bucket, which isn't great.
  })
})
```

Is there a way around this? Can I get acces to `req.body.email` BEFORE uploading the image to my S3 bucket? Is there a way for example to maybe both send a `formData` object AND `JSON` so I can first check the email before continuing with the file upload?

Comment: Are you using some auth methods ?

Comment: What do you mean? @Mykhaylo

Comment: I mean how you authorize users ? 
I can be jwt token ot smth else

Comment: I use JWT. @Mykhaylo

Comment: So include in JWT token some field from DB model which indicates that user has photo or not, so on the auth you will know user has photo or not, dont forgot update access token while field is changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just split it into 2 requests, let user thinks it's just 1 operation using AJAX:

1. Check User condition
2. If matched, allow to register and upload.

For more secure, Presigned Url works well. Signed url is like a temporary link with temporary permission used to upload to your S3, without this link, user cannot upload to your S3. Basically, the flow will be:

1. User requests to server to check condition and get signed url -> if matched, server responses with an url.

Not sure as if multer supports getting signed url, this code is using aws sdk:

```
router.post('/register', (req, res) => {
  // Check User exists
  // ...

  // Set custom info for the uploading image
  const fileName = uuid();
  const s3 = new S3();
  const params = {
    Bucket: 'bucket name',
    Key: 'file name',
    ContentType: 'image/*',
    Expires: 60 * 10, // Url is available for 10 mins
    Metadata: {
      'email': 'user@example.com',
      'custom-field': 'custom data',
    },
  };

  res.send(await s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', params));
});
```

2. User uses the url to upload to S3.

More info:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getSignedUrl-property

Comment: In the end this is what I went for. I didn't like splitting it up into 2 requests cuz it looks ugly. But if it works it works I guess hehe. Thank you for sharing your opinion :).

Comment: There's nothing wrong with sending 2 requests, the web world was more uglier before ajax :D and user won't see it our way. Anw, hope it helps :)